# How can I get RestSharp's current serializer/deserializer

Tags: c#, deserialization, dry, restsharp

How can I access RestSharp's current serializer/deserializer?

I am testing an API using RestSharp with the below code.

```
var client = new RestClient("http://EDDEVRGATES/Design_Time_Addresses/TaxFormsImportService");
var restRequest = new RestRequest("json/CreateAccount", Method.POST);
restRequest.RequestFormat = DataFormat.Json;
restRequest.AddBody(new Custom
{
    color="blue"
});
var response = client.Execute(restRequest);
```

I would like to be able to deserialize the `response.Content` using the same serializer that was used when the `client` executed the request. I am trying to avoid some kind of if `json` use this deserializer else `xml` use this deserializer.

I couldn't find any place where the serializer is exposed on the `RestClient` or `RestRequest`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

RestSharp maintains for each mimetype a different deserializer.

By default the following mimetypes are linked to these deserializers:

```
AddHandler("application/json", new JsonDeserializer());
AddHandler("application/xml", new XmlDeserializer());
AddHandler("text/json", new JsonDeserializer());
AddHandler("text/x-json", new JsonDeserializer());
AddHandler("text/javascript", new JsonDeserializer());
AddHandler("text/xml", new XmlDeserializer());
AddHandler("*", new XmlDeserializer());
```

If you want to use a JsonDeserializer, make sure you know the response mime-type. Then use the **AddHandler("response mime-type", new JsonDeserializer())** call to register that for that mimetype you want to use the JsonDeserializer.